# Reivsion in ScholarOne: Where to upload the response to reviewers as a attached file?

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals

For the revision, I found there are two possible attachment places for the response document.
I don't know which one is the appropriate place for attaching the document. Please help me!

One is in 'Step 1: View and Respond to Decision Letter'. At the end of the page, there is a sub-section named 'Attach a File:'.

The other is in 'Step 3: File Upload'. Similar to the first submission of the manuscript, I think the response document could be attached as *supplementary* file below the revised version of manuscript.

So where is the right place to attach the document responding to reviewers comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be uploaded as your response to the decision letter.

Comment: Thank you avid! I followed your advice. I've re-checked the instructions for my target journal and then found a guide similar to yours also.